# How to calculate distance and angle between two consecutive points in data frame?

Tags: r, distance

I have R's data frame:

```
my_data_points <- data.frame(x = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
 y = c(10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10))
```

How to calculate euclidean distance and angle between two consecutive points
p1(1, 10) and p2(2, 9), p2(2, 9) and p3(3, 8) etc.?

For example I can use this function for distance:

```
dist_func <- function(x1, x2, y1, y2) {
  sqrt((x2 - x1) ^ 2 + (y2 - y1) ^ 2)
}
```

but it uses data from two different rows. How to implement it?

Comment: You can use `my_data_points %>% mutate(new = map2(x, y, yourfun))`.  If you have the function to use, please do update in the post

Comment: by the angle you mean the angle between p1, p2 and the line parallel to the x axis that crosses p1

Comment: I can not implement my `dist_func` function with map2

Comment: `dist_func( head(mydf$x, -1), tail(mydf$x, -1), head(mydf$y, -1), tail(mydf$y, -1) )` ? Should be vectorised and quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the already defined `dist` function that by default calculates the matrix of euclidean distances, and using `atan2` to get the angle between the two points we can have the following:

```r
as.matrix(dist(my_data_points)) -> mat
c(mat[row(mat) == col(mat) + 1], NA) -> my_data_points$dists
my_data_points %>% mutate(angle = c(atan2(diff(x),diff(y)), NA) * 180/pi)
    x  y    dists angle
1   1 10 1.414214   135
2   2  9 1.414214   135
3   3  8 1.414214   135
4   4  7 1.414214   135
5   5  6 1.000000    90
6   6  6 1.414214    45
7   7  7 1.414214    45
8   8  8 1.414214    45
9   9  9 1.414214    45
10 10 10       NA    NA
```

Comment: The right-side assignment here is some real "some people want to watch the world burn" energy.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `lag` from `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
my_data_points %>% 
       mutate(out = dist_func(x, lag(x), y, lag(y)))
```